# Wordpress - Woocmmerce - Custom Theme - How to proper manage responsive images and aspect-ratio?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, responsive-images, srcset, child-theming

I need technical/conceptual advice on responsive images and aspect ratio.

I'm making an ecommerce, and I need that in the shop pages - all the pages that show product grids but not the individual product page - the images are displayed with an aspect ratio of 10:12 (width:height) for design reasons.
I also need to set the images so that the photo is downloaded as light (in kb) as possible based on the width of the viewport of the device.

For the download of the light images I read that there are srcset, and that wordpress implements them by default. If someone has already used them, is it better to modify them or are they already set in a way that make sense?
For the aspect ratio I saw that in the panel "customize wordpress -> woocommerce->images product" you can set the aspect ratio and you can change it on the fly even in the future if you have to change the design.
In addition, in "dashboard -> settings -> media" you have the possibility to change the size of the images and also here you can change on the fly.

It is not clear to me how to manage all these possibilities that coexist with each other.

Thinking to what I would like to get I need to figure out which way to take between:

1 - implement everything (how would you do that in terms of code and wordpress-dashboard settings?) so that when inserting a new product is not necessary to crop images with photoshop before loading in the library of wordpress, even starting from images loaded with ratio 1:1.
Then setting the 'fixed aspect ratio' in "customize -> Woocommerce -> products images" and uploading the images as if there were no tomorrow.

2 - Impose myself to prepare the images with the aspect ratio that I chose outside wordpress (photoshop) and load them in wordpress already with the correct ratio.
Then setting the aspect ratio "no cropping" in "customize -> Woocommerce -> Product images".

3 - Any other ideas?

Obviously I would prefer to waste as little time as possible when I have to upload new products, so it would be preferable the first way...

At the moment my css does not give any indication on how the images should be displayed, but they are resized (flex-grow:1) according to the width of the container(flex-parent with width in px).

Sorry for the complexity of the question, I tried to make it as clear as possible :)

My setup is Wordpress - Woocommerce - Child Theme.

---

My parent theme add these :

```php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

add_image_size( 'cashier-blog', 640 );
add_image_size( 'cashier-full-width', 1040 );

add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', array(
    'thumbnail_image_width' => 432,
    'single_image_width'    => 560,
) );
```

my actual image's html is:

```html
<img width="432" height="528" 
src="album-1-432x528.jpg" 
class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" 
alt="" 
srcset="
    album-1-432x528.jpg 432w, 
    album-1-500x611.jpg 500w" 
sizes="
    (max-width: 432px) 100vw, 
    432px">
```

---

Screenshots:

[desktop 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBj36.png)

[desktop 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U422.png)

[desktop 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI8b1.png)

[desktop 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK9g7.png)

[mobile 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exlJw.png)

[mobile 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi27n.png)